# angular cli failed optional dependency

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 on a chromebook via crouton.
When I went to install the angular cli I get this message-

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@angular/cli/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2
```

and when I run

```
ng --version
```

I get

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:17
>       constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js:3:18)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)

I honestly have no idea what is going wrong here. if there's any more information I can provide I'll be happy to do so, but I have no idea how to even go about trouble-shooting this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: uninstall and reinstall nodejs and try again

Comment: did that, same error still

Comment: I don't know what is the problem but I can tell you the warning is not related at all to the problem. `chokidar` is a library that watches directory/file changes and it relies on `fsevents` when it is used on OSX only (that's why this dependency is optional).